# How to typeset a math proof in beamer that displays line by line

Tags: beamer, math-mode, amsmath, pause

I'd like to display a step-by-step proof of a mathematics result. I want to have steps following other steps inside `amsmath`'s `align` environment, except **I want to `\pause` the slide after each line in the proof**, i.e. show one step at a time so that my students do not get distracted or confusing looking ahead in a slide.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage[protrusion,expansion,kerning,tracking,spacing]{microtype}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{multicol}

\usepackage{framed}

\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb,amsfonts}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\microtypecontext{spacing=nonfrench}
\nonfrenchspacing

\usetheme{Berkeley}

\usefonttheme{serif}

\begin{document}
    \section{Example 1}
    \begin{frame}[allowframebreaks]{\(u\)-substitution example}
        \begin{framed}
            Find the antiderivative of the function defined by \(f(x) = \frac{x}{\sqrt{x^2 + 4}}\).
        \end{framed}

        \begin{align}
            \intertext{Introduce the auxiliary variable $u$.}
            u &= x^2 + 4\\
            \intertext{Differentiate with respect to $x$.}
            \frac{du}{dx} &= 2x\\
            \intertext{Multiply through by the differential.}
            du &= 2x\,dx\\
            \intertext{Substitute $u$ into $f$.}
            f(x) &= \frac{x}{\sqrt{u}}\\
            \intertext{Substitute into antiderivative expression.}
            \int f(x)\,dx &= \int \frac{x}{\sqrt{u}}\,dx\\
            \intertext{Extract a constant.}
            &= \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{2x}{\sqrt{u}}\,dx
            \intertext{Rewrite differential in terms of $u$.}
            &= \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}\left(2x\,dx\right)\\
            &= \frac{1}{2}\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{u}}\,du
            \intertext{Apply the power rule for indefinite integration.}
            &= \frac{1}{2}\int u ^ {-\frac{1}{2}}\,du\\
            &= \frac{1}{2}\frac{\sqrt{u}}{1/2} + C\\
            &= \sqrt{u} + C
            \intertext{Substitute $u$.}
            \int f(x)\,dx &= \sqrt{x^2 + 4} + C
        \end{align}
    \end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: `[allowframebreaks]` doesn't fit for overlays.

Comment: @HarishKumar, I know. I was asking for a workaround.

Comment: There is no workaround if you mean one which allows you to use `allowframebreaks` and overlays for the same frame. The right way is to figure out what belongs on each slide and make up the frame content according to your design. Then you can use overlays. `allowframebreaks` is a hack for when you don't have the time or inclination to do it properly.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\uncover<x-y>`, most probably `\uncover<+->` (i.e., "uncover from here on") freely. It *doesn't* affect formatting in any way. Just make sure you don't introduce spurious spaces (the line end is a space for (La)TeX, unless the line ends with a comment started with `%`, spaces after a "protected" line end are ignored). E.g. I'd write something like:

```
\uncover<+->{%
   This is a step in my proof%
}%
\uncover<+->{%
   , continued here.
}
```

This way there is no stray space before the comma.

Answer (score 0):

I am not certain I understand the question.  It does not look as though the proof will fit on one slide, but put the second line you want as the argument of `\uncover<2->{.....}` and the third as the argument of `\uncover<3->{...}` and so on.  Here is an actual frame from a talk I gave recently:

```
\begin{frame}{Some properties of $G$ and $K$}

\begin{itemize}[<+->]

\item\hiblue{$G(D)$ is a subring of the perfect closure of the field of
fractions of $D$.}

\item\hiblue{The inner adjunction $R\to K(R)$ is an injection.}

\item\hiblue{The inner adjunction $R\to K(R)$ is epic in semiprime
rings.}

\item\hiblue{The induced $\spec(K(R))\to\spec(R)$ is a bijection.}


\end{itemize}

\uncover<5->{\hired{$K$ is {\bf domain reflective} if it takes
domains to domains.}}

\uncover<6->{$K_\fld$ is not domain reflective.}

\end{frame}
```

The first four items were also displayed one by one.